# Windows Server 2012 R2 Rescaning Disks Locks System

Tags: storage, windows-server-2012-r2, diskmanagement

I'm having an issue when re-scanning disks inside of the Windows Server Manager tool. When I go to:

```
File and Storage Services > Disks > Tasks > Rescan Stroage
```

the entire system locks up and blue screens. The bug check I get is a generic MACHINE_CHECK_EXECPTION. There is an Error event in the System Log just prior to the Kernel-Power event:

> The description for Event ID 1060 from source Application Popup cannot
>   be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed
>   on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can
>   install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> \SystemRoot\SysWow64\Drivers\ASPI32.SYS
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

### System Details:

```
OS:   Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
CPU:  Intel Core i7-2600K 3.40GHz
RAM:  G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 32GB DDR3 1333 SDRAM
Mobo: ASRock H77 Pro4-M
```

### Additional Details:

using 2x PCIe SIL3132 eSATA card connected to 
2 RSV-S8 External Enclosures which use Sil3726 port multipliers. I am not using 
RAID on the cards at all, but using Windows Storage Pools instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well... could be a number of things but generally speaking disk rescans causing lockups is often a side of a bad hard drive.  You could try removing each disk in turn and rescanning to see if it only fails when a specific disk is inserted.  If these are new disks or you've already run a diag on them and think they are fine then then I'd start checking for driver updates.  It could be any driver related to storage even USB storage or SD card readers or such that causes the BSOD upon scan initiation.  Make sure you've removed any and all unnecessary storage devices external USB peripherals, etc.

Comment: I've run a disk check on every disk and all come back clean. I've tried using a different card to connect to the 2 RSV-S8 bays. I've tried different BIOS versions on the mobo and eSATA cards (using latest currently). I've got the latest drivers for the mobo and both eSATA cards I've tried.
Also, I disabled the ASPI32.SYS driver since I know it's not being used and the system still locks up.